# Non-existence of Lorentz frame at rest on Earth

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, reference-frames, inertial-frames

So, I was reading Schutz First Course in General Relativity and in chapter 5 is states that " If SR is to be valid in a gravitational field, it is natural guess to assume that laboratory frame at rest on Earth is a Lorentz frame." I am not able to get why is it so?

Then, it goes on to show that from Pound-Rebka-Snider experiment, conclusion that we get from Minkowski geometry is wrong. How does this imply that reference frame at rest one earth is not inertial?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An inertial frame (i.e. a Lorentz frame) is, by definition, one in free fall. In an inertial frame, an object which is not subjected to *active* forces stays at rest, or moves uniformly in a straight line according to Newton's first law. In a

> laboratory frame at rest on Earth,

we are subject to active forces from the floor, pushing us upwards. So you are right, it is not natural to assume that this is an inertial frame.

This is confirmed in the Pound-Rebka experiment. If the lab frame were an inertial frame, then Minkowski geometry would hold in the lab frame, and there could be no redshift. The fact of a measured redshift shows that the lab frame is not an inertial frame. But we already knew that, because we can feel the force of the floor pushing us up.

We can also feel that the *apparent* force of gravity pulling us down acts in a way identical to other inertial forces, such as g-forces or centrifugal forces.

But strictly speaking, the definition of an inertial frame is not the Pound-Rebka experiment. It is that objects in free fall obey Newton's first law in an inertial frame. The results of the Pound-Rebka experiment are a consequence, not a reason.

Comment: Just so I understand, a locally inertial frame does *not* see any red-shifting in the Pound-Rebka experiment?

Comment: @Charlie, yes, that is right. Mind you, the Pound-Rebka experiment is hard enough to perform in a laboratory. I have no idea whether it could be set it up in an inertial frame!

Comment: Oh I was thinking if someone in free-fall was observing the PR experiment being performed by people on the surface of the Earth, not necessarily with the apparatus also in free fall with them, does this change the outcome?

Comment: I assume it would be very difficult in practice to perform it with the apparatus in free-fall since you'd need fairly precise equipment to avoid losing the "local" in local inertial frame.

Comment: Thank You. That clarifies the doubt.